# Tensorflow error : Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 640, 360, 3), found shape=(32, 360, 3)

Tags: python, pandas, linux, tensorflow, computer-vision

I recently made a CNN that detects humans with bounding boxes, I trained it and when I test it on an image I get the following error :     ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 640, 360, 3), found shape=(32, 360, 3)

I used this code to create and train the model :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print('1')

input_shape = (640, 360, 3)
Epochs = 5
Verbose = 1
Validation_split = 0.2


base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
base_model.trainable = False

inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x)

print('2')

label = np.load('labels.npy')
feed = np.load('array.npy')
print(label.shape)
print(feed.shape)
label = label.astype('float32')
print('ok')
feed = feed.astype('float32')
print('3')

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.losses.Huber(delta=1.0), metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()
  model.fit(feed,
            label,
            batch_size=128,
            validation_split=Validation_split,
            epochs=Epochs,
            verbose=Verbose)
  model.save('my_model(delta:0.1).keras')
```

and this is the code I used to test the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

image_path = '/home/tom-fiszelson/PycharmProjects/test/image_de_moi.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/home/tom-fiszelson/PycharmProjects/test/my_model(delta:0.1).keras')

image = cv2.resize(image, (640, 360))
cv2.imwrite('resized pic of me.png', image)
image_as_array = np.asarray(image)
image_as_array = np.transpose(image_as_array, (1, 0, 2))
print(image_as_array.shape)
bbox = model.pr
```

edict(image_as_array)
print(bbox)

The original image is 1280x720 pixels.
As I said before I have a weird error telling me my image array is (32, 360, 3) instead of (640, 360, 3) even though I know it's the right shape because my print (print(image_as_array.shape)) outputs (640, 360, 3).
Any thoughts on this ?